# htaccess Redirect a folder to a new URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following code:

```
Redirect /email http://email.secureserver.net
```

Which doesn't seem to be working.  Basically, I need to be able to redirect someone when they go to www.thedomain.com/email/ to http://email.secureserver.net

Now I want this to be able to work on my testing server and also when it goes live so I don't have to change the code.

So for testing the URL will be something like:

```
www.testingserver.com/clients/drews-garage/live/email/
```

And for when it goes live it will be:

```
www.thedomain.com/email/
```

So based on the code I provided above, that should work either way but it doesn't seem to work on my testing server.  I tried a 301 redirect to.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to use `mod_rewrite`'s `RewriteRule`. Rather than `mod_alias`'s `redirect`.

```
RewriteCond %{Request_URI} /email/?$
RewriteRule ^ http://email.secureserver.net [L,R=301]
```

The above will match `email/` in your URI path. So, `clients/drews-garage/live/email/` as well as `email/` will be matched.

---

```
Redirect /email http://email.secureserver.net
```

Is not working because of your URL: 
`www.testingserver.com/clients/drews-garage/live/email/`

The above is trying to redirect `www.testingserver.com/email/`

or `mod_alias` might not be loaded. But, `mod_alias` is usually loaded by default so this case is very unlikely.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked great. Is there an easier way to make it work without the trailing slash?  Right now I added a second RewriteRule and just used email instead of email/ but is there a shorter way to do that without adding another rule?  thanks!

Comment: @Drew check update. but now it will also match URLs like `www.testingserver.com/blahblahblah_myemail_blahblahblahblah...`

Comment: ahh, yeah I see that. that's very strange.  is that the only way around it? I noticed when I added my second rewrite for just email it did the same thing.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for all your help.  I learned a lot.