# .htaccess redirect user-account folder to a new url

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect all pages on a university server's user directory to a new url with the same folder structure without success. The instructions in other posts (for example, [htaccess Redirect a folder to a new URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366830/htaccess-redirect-a-folder-to-a-new-url)) don't work in this situation, which is this:

I want to redirect everything in this directory:

[http://www.someuniversity.edu/~xyz123](http://www.someuniversity.edu/%7Exyz123)

to this url:

https://mynewurl.com

The new url does NOT have any directory named ~xyz123.

The .htaccess files in other solutions end up trying to redirect everything in the ~xyz123 directory to a non-existent directory named ~xyz123 in https://mynewurl.com. Is there a way to redirect everything in the first address to the second, without adding ~xyz123 to the target address?

I only have access to the ~xyz123 folder. I can't place an .htaccess file in the folder above it.

Comment: You should show us what you tried, not just complain about how it didn't work as intended. Guessing you probably used the `Redirect` directive? That does prefix matching, and appends any excess parts of the original URL, to the substitution. Alternatives are `RedirectMatch`, or a `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for, it uses the rewriting module which has to be enabled inside the http host, obviously:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you implement this rule inside a distributed configuration file *inside* your user folder (`/~xyz123`), then the matching pattern (`^(.*)$`) will match the path relative inside that folder. Which should be what you want, the "pages" inside that folder. You can then append that part of the requested path to the target URL you want to redirect to. That drops the originally requested folder name, so your user name.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. Other things I tried included: 

```RewriteEngine On```
then a new line 
```RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?someuniversity\.edu/~xyz123/$ [NC]```
then another new line 
```RewriteRule ^/?~em36/ https://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]```

and a few others that are tricky to format here.

I now need to use the same file, I think, to make a similar redirect for anything in a subdirectory of my user public_html file. But this works perfectly. Thank you again.
```

Comment: @emendelson That condition does not make any sense at all. A host does not contain a path, `%{HTTP_HOST}` contains the requested _host name_ , not a URL. So that condition will never match.

Comment: @emendelson It is important that you understand _why_ this works. There is no sense in blindly copying some lines and enjoy something working. It is your site, you need to control it.

Comment: Yes, as I discovered when I actually looked up the syntax instead of blindly copying. I gave up on trying to format another comment with other things I tried, but one was `RedirectMatch permanent (\/|\/.*) https://newurl.com` - That redirected all pages the new home page, not to the actual pages. - Again, thank you again for the solution and explanations.